# SSL authentication in Java as Server/client model

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have a requirement to use client/server architecture and with Open SSL authentication. 
Here, how server to know the connect client using their OPen SSL certificate?
Anyone knows the link, sample then please reply me.We have to develop it in Java.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'OpenSSL authentication'. There is however 'SSL authentication'. Similarly there is no such thing as an 'OpenSSL certificate'. There are X.509 certificates; there are also for some reason SSH certificates, which have nothing to do with SSL. Your question remains unclear.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL is not Java, so your solution cannot be both - but I think I know what is intended.

Normally OpenSSL is used as part of Apache http as part of mod_ssl. This in turn uses a "connector" to send the requests to an application server, e.g. Apache Tomcat. You can configure this connector to also send the SSL certificates to tomcat if that is required, but normally the authentication/verification is handled within the deamon.

All this is pretty easy to Google, although you should factor in some time to fully understand the connectors. You've the keywords, now use them :)